# How to use an image asset with .ai extension in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, assets, photo

For example, *image.ai* is the file name. I am unable to use it regularly. Is there something specific I must to do use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ai` format is most commonly used for Adobe Illustrator.

This format is not directly usable in flutter, it is also not used directly in application and web-development as to my best knowledge this a propriety format.

**To use the asset in flutter you must export the asset from Adobe Illustrator to one of the formats supported in flutter such as `.png` or `.jpeg`**

If you must use a vector based format, you could try using the asset as an `.svg` with the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package

Answer (score 1):

The .ai format is the extension of Adobe Illustrator, and it cant be opened in any other app or development platform, except Adobe Suit. So you can just export your file as.png or.jpeg.
You can do this by going to the menu on the top file<<export<export for screens, then you can save it in different file formats as mentioned.